# Qual é o código que fizeram para a função print() e io.read() de Lua?

Tags: característica-linguagem, lua

Qual é o código que fizeram para a função `print()` e `io.read()` do Lua, quero fazer uma linguagem de programação então preciso saber.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando quer ver como funciona uma função em Lua vá até o [Github dela](https://github.com/lua/lua) e veja. Por exemplo [`print()`](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/6aeaeb5656a006ad95b35dd7482798fdc5f02f5e/lbaselib.c#L24) e [`io.read()`](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/05ba2880491fa1ecfe78d8a3542edcd6220e4022/liolib.c#L602). Tem que seguir o que ela vai chamando pra tentar entender o que faz, mas essas funções em específico claramente acabam chamando a API do sistema operacional.

Se avaliar todo fonte de Lua, e recomendo bastante para seu intento até por ser uma das linguagens úteis mais simples e bem escritas que existe, praticamente sem gambiarras e tudo bem pensado, verá que há um mapeamento para funções reais em C. Os módulos de Lua são apenas tabelas cujos elementos são as chaves para as funções em C e os valores um ponteiro para elas.

Embora eu goste da sua ideia, fazer uma linguagem de programação não é simples e o fato de não saber achar isso por conta própria faz pensar se está preparado para executar isso. A forma como Lua faz pode não servir para sua necessidade.

Comment: eu gostei de como faz, e eu estou procurando justamente pela api do sistema, pois vou começar com o prompt